# keycloak nodejs adapter unable to

Tags: node.js, express, keycloak, express-session

I am trying to get the nodejs adapter to working with my Express application and am getting issues after an authorisation code is returned for a user and then a subsequent request is made to exchange this for an access token.

Through some debugging of the library it seems the redirect_uri being sent in the subsequent request is blank, and when adding a breakpoint and inspecting the below code, I can see a session object is present, but there is no auth_redirect_uri property present

[image]

Watching the initial request when authorising the user, I can see the redirect_uri is present in the request query params.

[image]

So I can only think for some reason this is not being parsed out by the nodejs adapter after the user has been authorised and then persisted to the session object.

My express application does use the express-session middleware which I have configured to save sessions to a mongoDB. I then use my configured session store with the keycloak middleware configuration, in the same way as per this [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/example/index.js)

Can anyone offer any thoughts on what may be happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Keycloak are you using?

Comment: And also please include more context about you the first screenshot in your post? Where is this code from? Is it your code? The keycloak nodejs adapter?

Comment: @rckrd - I'm using 3.2.1. The code in the first image is take present in the adapter code from their grant manager module (keycloak-auth-utils\lib\grant-manager.js)

Comment: I also managed to debug further and found the session object does not have an auth_redirect_uri present. If I hard code this to what it should be I get an access token back. So either I'm doing something wrong in my setup of my client or the adapter is not behaving correctly for me. I do have a redirect url setup for my client which I see in the outgoing querystring of the initial user authentication request